# How to implement two slide-menu on both sides of a page in Onsen-UI?

Tags: onsen-ui

I'm new to Onsen-UI and would like to have slide-menus on both sides of my page. I intend to have multiple pages that will have this functionality and dont know how I can implement that. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to nest two different `ons-sliding-menu` like this:

```
<ons-sliding-menu
        main-page="page"
        menu-page="menu-left.html"
        side="left" ...>
</ons-sliding-menu>

<ons-template id="page">
    <ons-sliding-menu
            main-page="content.html"
            menu-page="menu-right.html"
            side="right" ...>
    </ons-sliding-menu>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="menu-left.html"> ... </ons-template>
<ons-template id="menu-right.html"> ... </ons-template>
<ons-template id="content.html"> ... </ons-template>
```

Working here: http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/qHeJx

Hope it helps :)

Comment: If it was useful for you, please, consider marking it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Fran, I just started using this a couple of days ago and still learning my way around. I just found where to mark as accepted, thanks.

Comment: This works great except when I slide it close it opens the other menu. Any way to avoid that?